# Using Airflow custom operator with Bitnami helm chart

Tags: airflow, bitnami, helm3

I have deployed Airflow on Minikube using the Bitnami helm chart based on [this](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/airflow). I have used Git sync to sync Dag files and plugin files like [this](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/airflow#loading-plugins). But when the Airflow pipeline was installed with helm, it can not import operators from plugins.

The structure of the plugins folder is like this:

```
plugins
├── dag_builder.py
└── operators
    ├── hello_operator.py
    ├── mysql_to_s3.py
    └── postgres_to_s3.py
```

In the dag file, I have imported the operator:

```
from operators.mysql_to_s3 import MySQLToS3ParquetOperator
```

`err: No module named 'operators`

How should I import custom operators here? It works when using docker-compose, but when using Bitnami Helm Chart it doesn't.